# Disabling href link click if {{permission}}

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Is it possible to disable an href link if for example: permission = user,

Here is my sample of hiding an element depending on permission:

```
<td ng-hide = "{{main.user}}" ng-show="main.admin">{{I'm hidden}}</td>
```

**How about disabling an href?**  Like: Disable a href click if = {{main.user}}

```
<a class="text-primary" href="stackoverflow">Click Me</a>
```

Comment: `ng-href="{{(main.user)?'stackoverflow':'#'}}"` use conditional statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hyperlinks don't support the `disabled` attribute. But you could create a CSS class that essentially does the same thing, like:

```
.disabled {
    cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

And then apply that class to the element conditionally:

```
<a ng-class="{disabled: notAllowed}">Link</a>
```

`notAllowed` is the expression that evaluates to true or false depending on if the user has permission or not.

You might also want to add a function that fires if the link is clicked, preventing the default action. You can then and add it to the element using the `ng-click` attribute:

```
<a ng-class="{disabled: notAllowed}" ng-click="stopClick($event)">Link</a>

$scope.stopClick = function($event) {
    if ($scope.notAllowed) {
        $event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Of course, this can easily be disabled by the user since it's client-side. But that's true with any JavaScript.